# lvalue required as left operand of assignment for operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, member-functions

I am trying to do operator overloading but keep getting an error when I run this code from the .cpp

The header file prototype looks like this,

`const Velocity & operator = (const Velocity & rhs);`

And the .cpp member function looks like this.

```
const Velocity & Velocity :: operator = (const Velocity & rhs)
{
   this->getDx() = rhs.getDx();
   this->getDy() = rhs.getDy();
   this->getX() = rhs.getX();
   this->getX() = rhs.getY();
   return *this;
}
```

where in main using the operator looks like.

```
Velocity v1;
Velocity v2;
Velocity v3;

promptVelocity("Enter values for Velocity 1", v1);
promptVelocity("Enter values for Velocity 2", v2);

// Test operator =
v3 = v1;
cout << "Test operator = : " << v3 << endl;
```

I am getting the error for this-> lines

```
lvalue required as left operand of assignment
```

Please help!

Comment: A getter being assignable is... odd, and probably incorrect.  Don't you think you should show us their declarations?  Also, an assignment operator returning a const reference is odd... are you trying to protect against something like `(x=y)=z`?  Seems unnecessary.

Comment: First of all - we are guessing your getters implementation. Secondly, you should create a minimum working example of your problem. Thirdly, why do you think, that using getter method to set value is a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

Change your function to:

```
Velocity& Velocity::operator=(const Velocity& rhs) {
  dx_ = rhs.getDx();
  dy_  = rhs.getDy();
  x_ = rhs.getX();
  y_ = rhs.getY();
  return *this;
}
```

... assuming that "dx_", "dy_", etc. are the names of the actual variables. The left hand side of the assignment has to be an "lvalue" (to define it simply -- a named variable with an address), whereas before you were using an "rvalue" (the temporary variable that was returned as a result of the corresponding "get" functions). To go into this in  a little more detail, most likely your various "get" functions return an object of a value type (e.g. "int") or a const reference (like "const int&"), but to assign to something, you really need a mutable reference (e.g. "int&"). Assigning to the output of a "get" function that returns a simple value type is meaningless, because what the get function is doing is creating a *copy* of the underlying data before returning it. Although this copy may have a memory address associated with it (e.g. if it was stored on the stack, for example), assigning to it would produce no observable effect, because this copy doesn't do anything or get seen anywhere unless it is assigned to some variable. When you use the name of a member variable on the left hand side, however, the assignment actually makes sense since the variable receiving the assignment can still be referred to elsewhere.

I should also note that in my change I removed a bunch of superfluous `this->`es. There are only two cases where `this->` is strictly necessary:

1. There is a symbol of the same name that "overshadows" the member of `this` (e.g. a parameter or other local variable that is more narrowly scoped than the class scope), in which case it is necessary to use `this->` to choose the member over the local.
2. Very imprecisely: a `template` is involved such that it is necessary to use `this->` explicitly to make C++ look in this class rather than in the namespace scope (see [dependent name lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) for a somewhat more precise explanation).

In the absence of these two cases, the symbol lookup will correctly find the member variables without `this->` and thus it is redundant and, therefore, to be avoided (in my opinion).

In addition, I changed the return type of the assignment from "const Velocity&" to "Velocity&",  because assignment operators typically return a mutable instance of the assigned object and to do otherwise could be surprising; for example, making the function return a const breaks:

```
Velocity velocity = // ...
Velocity default_vaue = // ...
// ... many lines later ...
if (/* some condition /*) {
  ReassignIfInvalid(velocity = ComputeSomething(), default_value);
}
```

... where the function "ReassignIfInvalid" requires that the parameter be mutable so that it can conditionally overwrite the value. While the code above may not be the best code to emulate, it will nevertheless prove surprising if the output of an assignment is immutable.

Comment: Chained assignment works properly whether or not the reference returned is const. There are good reasons to return a non-const ref, but making `x = y = z` work isn't one of them.

Comment: @T.C. I forgot to add my parentheses. Regardless, the general point that it is necessary for chaining invocations of mutable operations still stands.

Comment: Do we really care about the `(x=y)=z` case?  Who is writing that code?

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan I have access to the the dx and dy variables but the x and y variable are private. In order to assign them would I have to use my get function for them?

Comment: @Ed, that case, probably not, but if (Process(x = y)) where "Process" takes a mutable object is something one might care about. It is very surprising / non-standard for assignment to return a const.

Comment: @gman54, no you don't need to use the "get" functions... a class can access its own "private" variables.

Answer (score 0):

In the .cpp function, you're are telling that a getter function should get a value from another function, so you're not doing something really. If you have it, use a setter function. Althrough you might better make your values public instead of using getters and setters.

Comment: I  would make the variable public but the assignment calls for private variables

Comment: do not make a variable public, use settter methods

Comment: but using getter and setter methods it's almost like it was a public variable, isn't it?